# Ajax request sending POST and GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using Ajax to submit form data to another page and then redirect the browser to that page. This is the code I'm using:

```
    $(".step").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/dashboard/step2/",
            type: "post",
            data: paramObj,
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                window.location.href="/dashboard/step2/";
            }
        });
    });
```

However, this code sends a POST and a GET request. This causes other problems because I have other functions that rely on the fact that the only the request being sent is a POST request. Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: What problems does it cause?  How should it behave?

Comment: I have another function that exits when a GET request is sent

Answer (score 3):

This is causing a GET because you're telling the browser to navigate to /dashboard/step2/ by issuing the command `window.location.href="/dashboard/step2/";`

Comment: I know that. What I want to do is to redirect to that page without explicitly specifying that

Comment: So why are you using AJAX? The browser is perfectly capable of posting form data to a URL without javascript.

Comment: I am taking data from multiple forms to submit to another page which runs other functions

Comment: nvm I fixed it. Just restructured the entire form

Comment: Please post an answer showing how you solved this, so that it may help future visitors.  Are you willing to do that, or should I ask that the question be deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Submit the form after `ajax success` like this:

```
$(".step").submit(function(e) {
    var form = $(this);
    if (form.data('success') != '1') { // run this if ajax call is not completed
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/dashboard/step2/",
            type: "post",
            data: paramObj,
            success: function(response) {
                form.data('success', '1');
                $(".step").submit();
            }
        });
    }
});
```